# AngularJS directive not recognised when starting with data-*

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-directive

I'm new to AngularJS. Need some help with the directive I created.
This is My HTML:

```
<data-table template-url="dataTable.html" info="someData"></data-table>
```

I get "someData" from server in my controller - directive.js:

```
app.directive('dataTable', function() {
 return{
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        data : '=info'
    },
    link: function($scope,elem,attrs){
         ///some code here.
    },
    templateUrl : function(elem, attrs) {
        return attrs.templateUrl;
    }
});
```

The issue is when I debug my code, it come to the directive by doesn't go inside. (I used javascript debug in chrome). Is there anything I'm missing. The restrict Tag is proper, name is correct what else is needed? I did look at the similar questions but couldn't find any solution. Here is a fiddle : [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7neze6zu/)

Comment: i think the syntax for directive is wrong.

Comment: Can you point out the error/point where i made the mistake. @HJz

Comment: `templateUrl` should be a string, so, maybe, your directive is loaded, but it just cant find a template.

Comment: I put a break point inside the directive on return statement. It doesn't come inside only. and the function returns a string i.e. attrs.templateUrl ( is a String).

Comment: please create a demo

Comment: @HJz please take a look at the demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can't use directive names starting with `data-*` because its reserved by AngularJS [ng core namespaces](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng).** Just use an other name to start with and you will be fine.

```
<my-data-table template-url="dataTable.html" info="someData"></my-data-table>
```

And your directive:

```
myApp.directive('myDataTable', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      data: '=info'
    },
    link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
      ///some code here.
      console.log(attrs.templateUrl);
    },
    templateUrl: function(elem, attrs) {
       return attrs.templateUrl;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: can you explain me why this happened. I thought It was Ok to use camelcase notation for naming the derictives, like ngRepeate or any other.

Comment: @Iin I have also use - in element name before and it worked fine.

Comment: Sure no worries, Ty you saved a lot of my time.